# How to use sdimage in uiimage caching?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdwebimage, photosframework

Anyway to handle or display UIImage with caching and with placeholder?

I have found one answer from stack exchange but it didnot work for me given below the link :

[Best way to cache images on ios app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511548/best-way-to-cache-images-on-ios-app)

Notes: I dont have any URL because i get image object of PHIMAGE asset library.

Comment: There's no need to cache when you are using image asset library. The images are copied to your bundle when build so they are always there.

Comment: Where is your image in local bundle or Server?

Comment: Are you using [PHImageManager](http://nshipster.com/phimagemanager/)?

Comment: @rptwsthi, my all images are in photo library means in iPhone.

Comment: @jasper i am using PHImagemanager.

Comment: @Jasper I think you are right i check it properly and issue is solved automatically. there is an issue about reload the cell but rightnow it is solved by me. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)
It is very simple to display and cache image.

```
[imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.image_url.com"]
                  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Comment: But i dont have any URL i have an image of phimage object so i cant get any URL

Answer (score 0):

You can use a very usefull library called [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

SDWebImage automagically cache all your images when you provide a valid URL with the `sd_setImageWithURL`. So the next time you call it, will use the cache system instead of re-download the image.

Example to implement in a `UIImageView` from their github:

```
// Here we use the new provided sd_setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
[cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
                  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Comment: But i dont have any URL i have an image of phimage object so i cant get any URL

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem of smoothing an all image while scroll the table but there is an issue of reload the cell not the caching problem i solved this issue.

I get an image one by one from local identifier which is provided by PHAsset framework and display that image into cell.

For reference Code:

PHFetchResult *savedAssets = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers:@[your local identifier] options:nil];
        [savedAssets enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PHAsset *asset, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

```
        //this gets called for every asset from its localIdentifier you saved
        PHImageRequestOptions * imageRequestOptions = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
        imageRequestOptions.synchronous = YES;
        imageRequestOptions.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeFast;

        [[PHImageManager defaultManager]requestImageForAsset:asset targetSize:CGSizeMake(50,50) contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill options:imageRequestOptions resultHandler:^(UIImage * _Nullable result, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
            NSLog(@"You get an image from result");

        }];
    }];
```