# Which is the best way to cache the data from API's in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Which the best way to cache the data getting from API in swift?

I am using alamofire to hit the api's. So the data i am getting from API's includes some text and large images. I just want to cache them to improve the performance of my app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511548/best-way-to-cache-images-on-ios-app

Comment: Create a NSobject Utility class to store all data