# How to cache Images for IOS and Android in react native?

Tags: android, ios, image, caching, react-native

I am new to react native, building an app, that uses a gallery where I can swipe to another image, zoom in, scroll on zoomed images, just passing the url for the images. But there is no cache in it. Reading the [Images](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/docs/Images.md) documentation. It does not have Cache for Android till the current date.

Using the [prefetch](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#prefetch) maybe solve the problem, but I have to modify the library. I have tried others, that also need to modify library, and ended up losing some properties.

How to cache the images without hacking the library? Is there a library that I can cache based on URL?

Comment: There are lots of Library but if you want native stuffs : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511548/best-way-to-cache-images-on-ios-app

Comment: @ArunKumar, thanks for your answer, but not exactly, I do not want native stuff. But if it is the only way, i will go for it, so far i want React Native approaches.

Comment: So, the resolution was hack the library i am using and add a caching library that handle both for IOS and Android. Thanks to all who tried to answer this!

Answer (score -2):

I solved the problem, I forked the repos, modified it using a library that caches for IOS and Android, and installed from the forked repo.