# Loading Table Values on Separate Thread

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, parallel-processing, grand-central-dispatch

I have the following bit of code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^
{
    [self loadThumbnails]; //loads an array of photos which get loaded into each table cell
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
});
```

in the initializer of my subclassed `UITableView`. I'd like it for the table to load these thumbnails on a separate thread because they take some time to load. Yet, when I execute the above code, the tableview comes up blank. So my first question is how can I fix this?

My second question is, I'd like for this dispatch queue to be killed once the tableview object is released. Is this possible / how would this be accomplished?

Tried implementing the solution from Vikings and here is what I got:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"ThumbnailCell";
    UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [self dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];    

    if (!tableViewCell)
    {
        tableViewCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }


    NSInteger thumbnailsPerCell = self.thumbnailViewsPerCell;
    NSInteger startingThumbnailIndex = indexPath.row * thumbnailsPerCell;
    NSInteger totalThumbnails = MIN(((indexPath.row * thumbnailsPerCell) + thumbnailsPerCell) , [self.thumbnailViews count]) - startingThumbnailIndex;

    if ([tableViewCell.contentView subviews])
    {
        for (UIView *subview in [tableViewCell.contentView subviews]) 
        {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < totalThumbnails; i++)
    {
        UIView *thumbnailView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i * self.cellDimension, 0, self.cellDimension, self.cellDimension)];
        UIView *thumbnail = [[self.thumbnailCache objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]] retain];
        if (thumbnail)
        {
            [thumbnailView addSubview:thumbnail];
            [tableViewCell.contentView addSubview:thumbnailView];
            [thumbnailView release];
            [thumbnail release];
        }
        else 
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), 
            ^{
                UIView *thumbnail = [[self createThumbnailAtIndex:i] retain];

                if (thumbnail)
                {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), 
                    ^{
                        UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [self cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

                        if (tableViewCell)
                        {
                            [thumbnailView addSubview:thumbnail];
                            [tableViewCell.contentView addSubview:thumbnailView];
                            [thumbnailView release];
                            [thumbnail release];
                        }
                    });

                    [self.thumbnailCache setObject:thumbnail forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
                }
            });
        }
    }

    return tableViewCell;
}
```

This is producing a blank tableView. Any clue as to why?

Comment: Does [self loadThumbnails] block until done or does it return immediately?

Comment: That's the problem then. You end up calling reloadData while all the images continue to load in the background. you need to set this up such that reload data is called as each image is load or once all images have finished loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, and solved it perfectly, check the thread below.  Just load the images in a separate thread, a technique referred to as lazy loading.

[Table View Scrolling Async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486828/table-view-scrolling-async)

Comment: Thank you sir. I've tried implementing this exact algorithm and am getting a blank table. I've posted the code above. Any chance you could take a look?

Comment: @CoDEFRo you mention you get a blank table view with no cells?  You should at least get a cell, or your method is not returning a cell.  Also, why are you removing the subviews from your table view cell?

Comment: @CoDEFRo What kind of datasource are you using for the table view?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, I am using the UITableViewDataSource. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I was getting a blanktableview with no cells, but I fixed a bug and now it's a blanktableview with cells. I think part of the problem is the adding and removing off subviews. Maybe this type of algorithm is not needed for what I'm doing since I'm not loading from outside of my apps bundle. What do you think?

Comment: WWDC2012 Building Concurrent User Interfaces helped as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of strange to mix GCD with performSelector. I would do it this way:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^
{
    [self loadThumbnails]; //loads an array of photos which get loaded into each table cell
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
        [self reloadData];
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

answering your second question:
maybe you shouldn't load all thumbnails for your table. Just load those ones you need to display in separate requests. You could even cancel previous requests if cell has changed the thumbnail image.
There are even libraries which do everything for you like [SBWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Comment: The OP indicates that the class is a subclass of `UITableView`. Therefore, `self` is correct.

Comment: Generally speaking, it's recommended that answers be more than just the necessary code. Explanations and the like are appreciated. You'll get more upvotes with more thorough answers.

Comment: @Mac, you are right, sorry, i missed that thing, i will edit my answer